# Packet sniffer in python using pcapy impacket

Tags: python, packet-sniffers, impacket, pcapy

I'm trying to create a packet sniffer using pcapy and impacket. I'm stuck with data extraction phase. Unfortunately impacket is not properly documented. At least i could n't find one. Could anyone tel me where to find the documentation or what functions i could use to extract data from captured packet?

**edit**

my current code

```
import datetime
import pcapy
import sys
from impacket.ImpactPacket import *
from impacket.ImpactDecoder import *

def main(argv):

    dev='ppp0'
    print "Sniffing device " + dev

    cap = pcapy.open_live(dev , 65536 , 1 , 0)

    while(1) :
        try:
            (header, packet) = cap.next()            
            eth= LinuxSLLDecoder().decode(packet)
            ip=eth.child()  #internet layer
            trans=ip.child()#transport layer

            try:                
                print 'protocol=',
                if ip.get_ip_p() == UDP.protocol:
                    print 'UDP'
                if ip.get_ip_p() == TCP.protocol:
                    print 'TCP','port=',trans.get_th_dport()
                    print trans.child()
                if ip.get_ip_p() == ICMP.protocol:
                    print 'ICMP'

                print 'src=',ip.get_ip_src(),'dest=',ip.get_ip_dst()

                print ''

            except:
                pass


        except pcapy.PcapError:
            continue             


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv)
```

**Sample Output**

```
src= xxx.xxx.xxx.xx dest= xx.xxx.xx.xx

protocol= TCP port= 443

1703 0300 2400 0000 0000 0000 07e2 a2a5    ....$...........
09fe 5b15 3cf1 803d 0c83 8ada 082e 8269    ..[.<..=.......i
0007 8b33 7d6b 5c1a 01                     ...3}k\..
```

What i want to do is extract more data, For example extract the url (if there is a url in packet)

Comment: Could you show us what your efforts have been so far?

Comment: @RyPeck I edit the question as you asked.

Comment: @User Thanks. Sorry i couldn't Vote up your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar problem. I guess when there is no documentation, the best documentation is the source code! And with python we are lucky to have source code most of the time. Anyway, I would suggest looking into `ImpactDecoder.py` and `ImpactPacket.py`. First one give some insights as far as how packets get decoded and second gives information on actual packets as a class and their methods. For instance, `ImpactPacket.py` and class `PacketBuffer` has following methods that you were probably looking for::

```
def set_bytes_from_string(self, data):
    "Sets the value of the packet buffer from the string 'data'"
    self.__bytes = array.array('B', data)

def get_buffer_as_string(self):
    "Returns the packet buffer as a string object"
    return self.__bytes.tostring()

def get_bytes(self):
    "Returns the packet buffer as an array"
    return self.__bytes

def set_bytes(self, bytes):
    "Set the packet buffer from an array"
    # Make a copy to be safe
    self.__bytes = array.array('B', bytes.tolist())

def set_byte(self, index, value):
    "Set byte at 'index' to 'value'"
    index = self.__validate_index(index, 1)
    self.__bytes[index] = value

def get_byte(self, index):
    "Return byte at 'index'"
    index = self.__validate_index(index, 1)
    return self.__bytes[index]

def set_word(self, index, value, order = '!'):
    "Set 2-byte word at 'index' to 'value'. See struct module's documentation to understand the meaning of 'order'."
    index = self.__validate_index(index, 2)
    ary = array.array("B", struct.pack(order + 'H', value))
    if -2 == index:
        self.__bytes[index:] = ary
    else:
        self.__bytes[index:index+2] = ary

def get_word(self, index, order = '!'):
    "Return 2-byte word at 'index'. See struct module's documentation to understand the meaning of 'order'."
    index = self.__validate_index(index, 2)
    if -2 == index:
        bytes = self.__bytes[index:]
    else:
        bytes = self.__bytes[index:index+2]
    (value,) = struct.unpack(order + 'H', bytes.tostring())
    return value

def set_long(self, index, value, order = '!'):
    "Set 4-byte 'value' at 'index'. See struct module's documentation to understand the meaning of 'order'."
    index = self.__validate_index(index, 4)
    ary = array.array("B", struct.pack(order + 'L', value))
    if -4 == index:
        self.__bytes[index:] = ary
    else:
        self.__bytes[index:index+4] = ary

def get_long(self, index, order = '!'):
    "Return 4-byte value at 'index'. See struct module's documentation to understand the meaning of 'order'."
    index = self.__validate_index(index, 4)
    if -4 == index:
        bytes = self.__bytes[index:]
    else:
        bytes = self.__bytes[index:index+4]
    (value,) = struct.unpack(order + 'L', bytes.tostring())
    return value

def set_long_long(self, index, value, order = '!'):
    "Set 8-byte 'value' at 'index'. See struct module's documentation to understand the meaning of 'order'."
    index = self.__validate_index(index, 8)
    ary = array.array("B", struct.pack(order + 'Q', value))
    if -8 == index:
        self.__bytes[index:] = ary
    else:
        self.__bytes[index:index+8] = ary

def get_long_long(self, index, order = '!'):
    "Return 8-byte value at 'index'. See struct module's documentation to understand the meaning of 'order'."
    index = self.__validate_index(index, 8)
    if -8 == index:
        bytes = self.__bytes[index:]
    else:
        bytes = self.__bytes[index:index+8]
    (value,) = struct.unpack(order + 'Q', bytes.tostring())
    return value


def get_ip_address(self, index):
    "Return 4-byte value at 'index' as an IP string"
    index = self.__validate_index(index, 4)
    if -4 == index:
        bytes = self.__bytes[index:]
    else:
        bytes = self.__bytes[index:index+4]
    return socket.inet_ntoa(bytes.tostring())

def set_ip_address(self, index, ip_string):
    "Set 4-byte value at 'index' from 'ip_string'"
    index = self.__validate_index(index, 4)
    raw = socket.inet_aton(ip_string)
    (b1,b2,b3,b4) = struct.unpack("BBBB", raw)
    self.set_byte(index, b1)
    self.set_byte(index + 1, b2)
    self.set_byte(index + 2, b3)
    self.set_byte(index + 3, b4)
```

The other super useful class from `ImpactPacket.py` is `ProtocolLayer`, that gives us following methods::

```
def child(self):
    "Return the child of this protocol layer"
    return self.__child

def parent(self):
    "Return the parent of this protocol layer"
    return self.__parent
```

So, basically impacket uses matreshka doll approach, and you can go to any layer you want using child and parent methods and use any methods of the `PacketBuffer` class on any layer. Pretty cool, huh? Furthermore, particular layers (or packets) have their specific methods but you would have to go dig `ImpactPacket.py` and `ImpactDecoder.py` if you want to find more about those.

Good luck and cheers mate!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for a syn-port scanner with pcap and python and impacket.
Maybe you can tak the important parts out of it.

```
'''
synscan.py ...
see scan.py for parameters

this works extremely well an a windows that likes to communicate
scanning hosts in same ethernet is possible
scanning host not within the same ethernet may success but does not need to

many algorithms were tried

-   raw socket support needs higher previleges
    and is impossible because windows does not allow to sniff with them
    or to submit sniffable packets
->  not implemented here

    "Why do you need special libraries for TCP-SYN scans?"
    thats why.

using pcap the program is devided into phases
usually it succeeds in phase 1.
phase 0:
    add targets and phase 1
phase 1+: (parallel)
    send arp request to resolve target
    bombard it with the right packets
    sniff
phase 2:
    send out udp to resolve mac address by sniffing
    send out raw socket tcp syn requests (need higher previleges) optional
phase 3:
    if not yet succeeded in phase 1: = mac not found
    bombard all macs with packets
phase 4:
    bombard broadcasting [mac ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff] with packets
phase 5:
    clean up - no use

use DEBUG_PHASE to show phases

currently only ipv4 is supported

'''


import sys
import time
import thread
import pcap # pcapy
import impacket
import random

import impacket.ImpactDecoder as ImpactDecoder
import impacket.ImpactPacket as ImpactPacket

import array

import scan
from scan import *

DEFAULT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 20
NOTIFY_TIMEOUT = 2

# argument incdeces for socket.socket(...)
SOCK_INIT_FAMILY = 0
SOCK_INIT_TYPE = 1
SOCK_INIT_PROTO = 2

STATE_STATE = 1
STATE_TIME = 0

PCAP_ARGS = ()
PCAP_KW = dict(promisc = True, timeout_ms = 0)

DEBUG = False
DEBUG_IFACE =   False and DEBUG # put out which devices are set up
DEBUG_IP =      False and DEBUG # print ip debug output for ip packets v4
DEBUG_ARP =     False and DEBUG # send arp communication debug out
DEBUG_SYN =     False and DEBUG # print out the syn requests sent
DEBUG_PACKET =  False and DEBUG # packet inspection as seen by scanner
DEBUG_PHASE =   True and DEBUG # scanner phases - 5
DEBUG_STATE =   False and DEBUG # debug output about the state
DEBUG_PHASE2 =  False and DEBUG # debug output about what is sent in phase 2
                                 # you need higher previleges for some of these operations

ETHER_BROADCAST = (0xff,) * 6 # mac ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff


# --- Conversions --------------------------------------------------------------

def ip_tuple(ip):
    '''Decode an IP address [0.0.0.0] to a tuple of bytes'''
    return tuple(map(int, ip.split('.')))

def tuple_ip(ip):
    '''Encode a a tuple of bytes to an IP address [0.0.0.0]'''
    return '.'.join(map(str, (ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3])))

# --- Packet Creation --------------------------------------------------------------

def generate_empty_arp_request():
    # build ethernet frame
    eth = ImpactPacket.Ethernet()
    eth.set_ether_type(0x0806)          # this is an ARP packet
    eth.set_ether_dhost(ETHER_BROADCAST)# destination host (broadcast)

    # build ARP packet
    arp = ImpactPacket.ARP()
    arp.set_ar_hrd(1)
    arp.set_ar_hln(6)                   # ethernet address length = 6
    arp.set_ar_pln(4)                   # ip address length = 4
    arp.set_ar_pro(0x800)               # protocol: ip
    arp.set_ar_op(1)                    # opcode: request
    arp.set_ar_tha(ETHER_BROADCAST)     # target hardware address (broadcast)
    eth.contains(arp)
    return eth, arp

def generate_empty_ip_packet():
    eth = ImpactPacket.Ethernet()
    #### values to be set:
    # type, shost, dhost
    eth.set_ether_type(0x800)

    ip = ImpactPacket.IP()

    #### values to be set:
    # version, IHL, TOS, total_length, ID, Flags, Fragment offset, 
    # TTL, Protocol, Checksum, source_addr, destination_addr, options
    ip.set_ip_v(4)  
    ip.set_ip_hl(5)   # 5 * 32 bit
    ip.set_ip_tos(0)  # usal packet -> type of service = 0
    # total_length
    ip.set_ip_id(random.randint(1, 0xffff)) 
    ip.set_ip_df(0)   # flags redundant
    ip.set_ip_off(0)
    ip.set_ip_ttl(250)
    ip.set_ip_p(6)    # tcp = 6
    eth.contains(ip)
    return eth, ip

# --- Scanner --------------------------------------------------------------


def start_scan(timeout):
    '''return a scanner object


'''
    # mac addresses are used to send ethernet packages
    mac_addresses = {} # ip : set([mac])
    # threadsave access to the targets
    targets_lock = thread.allocate_lock()
    targets = [] # (family, (ip, port, ...))
    # list of target names
    target_hosts = set() # host ips

    def is_target(host):
        return host in target_hosts

    def add_target(family, address):
        target_hosts.add(address[IP])
        mac_addresses.setdefault(address[IP], set())
        with targets_lock:
            targets.append((family, address))

    def store_ip_mac_resolution_for(host):

        for family, socktype, proto, canonname, address in \
                                    socket.getaddrinfo(host, 0):
            mac_addresses.setdefault(address[IP], set())

    def associate_ip_mac(ip, mac):
        if ip in mac_addresses or is_target(ip):
            if type(mac) is list:
                hashable_array_constructor = ('B', ''.join(map(chr, mac)))
            else:
                hashable_array_constructor = (mac.typecode, mac.tostring())
            mac_addresses[ip].add(hashable_array_constructor)

    def get_macs(host):
        macs = set()
        empty_set = set()
        for family, socktype, proto, canonname, (ip, port) in \
                                    socket.getaddrinfo(host, 0):
            macs.update(mac_addresses.get(ip, empty_set))
        return [array.array(*mac) for mac in macs]

    def get_local_macs():
        macs = set()
        for ip in get_host_ips():
            for mac in get_macs(ip):
                macs.add((ip, tuple(mac.tolist())))
        return macs

    def ip_known(ip):
        return bool(mac_addresses.get(ip, False))

    def save_ip_mac_resolution(ether, ip_header):
        source_ip = ip_header.get_ip_src()
        source_mac = ether.get_ether_shost()
        associate_ip_mac(source_ip, source_mac)

        destination_ip = ip_header.get_ip_dst()
        destination_mac = ether.get_ether_dhost()
        associate_ip_mac(destination_ip, destination_mac)

    ## parse data directly from pcap

    def find_connection_response(data):
        # Parse the Ethernet packet
        decoder = ImpactDecoder.EthDecoder()
        find_connection_response_ethernet(decoder.decode(data))

    def find_connection_response_ethernet(ether):
        eth_type = ether.get_ether_type()
        if eth_type == 0x800: 
            # Received an IP-packet (2048)
            # Parse the IP packet inside the Ethernet packet
            find_connection_response_ip(ether, ether.child())
        elif eth_type == 0x0806:
            store_mac_of_target(ether)

    ## arp response handling

    def store_mac_of_target(ether):
        arp = ether.child()
        if arp.get_ar_op() in (2, ):
            if DEBUG_ARP:print 'response'
            # Received ARP Response
            source_mac_addr         = arp.get_ar_sha()
            source_ip_addr          = tuple_ip(arp.get_ar_spa())
            destination_mac_addr    = arp.get_ar_tha()
            destination_ip_addr     = tuple_ip(arp.get_ar_tpa())
            if DEBUG_ARP:print source_mac_addr, source_ip_addr, destination_mac_addr, destination_ip_addr
            if is_target(destination_ip_addr):
                if DEBUG_ARP:print 'intersting:', destination_ip_addr, destination_mac_addr
                associate_ip_mac(destination_ip_addr, destination_mac_addr)
            if is_target(source_ip_addr):
                if DEBUG_ARP:print 'intersting:', source_ip_addr, source_mac_addr
                associate_ip_mac(source_ip_addr, source_mac_addr)

    ## tcp syn-ack response handling

    def find_connection_response_ip(ether, ip_header):
        save_ip_mac_resolution(ether, ip_header)
        if ip_header.get_ip_p() == 0x6:
            # Received a TCP-packet
            # Parse the TCP packet inside the IP packet
            if DEBUG_IP > 2:
                print 'received ip packet: %s to %s' % (ip_header.get_ip_src(), \
                                                      ip_header.get_ip_dst())
            source_ip = ip_header.get_ip_src()
            destination_ip = ip_header.get_ip_dst()
            if not is_target(source_ip):
                return
            if DEBUG_IP > 1:print 'found interest in: %s' % ip_header.get_ip_src()
            find_connection_response_tcp(ip_header, ip_header.child())

    def find_connection_response_tcp(ip_header, tcp_header):
        # Only process SYN-ACK packets
        source_ip = ip_header.get_ip_src()
        source_port = tcp_header.get_th_sport()
        destination_ip = ip_header.get_ip_dst()
        destination_port = tcp_header.get_th_sport()
        print targets
        if tcp_header.get_SYN() and tcp_header.get_ACK():

            # Get the source and destination IP addresses

            # Print the results
            if DEBUG_IP: print("Connection attempt %s:(%s) <- %s:%s" % \
                              (source_ip, source_port, \
                               destination_ip, destination_port))
            if source_ip in target_hosts:
                put_port(source_port)
        elif tcp_header.get_SYN() and not tcp_header.get_ACK() and source_ip in get_host_ips():
            # someone sent a syn request along
            # asuming the acknoledge will come here, too
            target = (socket.AF_INET, (destination_ip, destination_port))
            if DEBUG_IP: print("Connection attempt %s:(%s) --> %s:%s" % \
                              (source_ip, source_port, \
                               destination_ip, destination_port))
            with targets_lock:
                try:
                    targets.remove(target)
                except ValueError:
                    pass

    def put_port(port):
        sys.stdout.write(str(port) + '\n')

    ## syn packet sending

    def send_syn(family, addr):
        if family == socket.AF_INET:
            send_syn_ipv4(addr)
        elif family == socket.AF_INET6:
            pass
        else:
            sys.stderr.write('Warning: in send_syn: family %s not supported\n' \
                             % family)

    def send_syn_ipv4(address):
        for packet in iter_syn_packets(address):
            if DEBUG_PACKET:
                print 'packet', id(packet)
            send_packet(packet)

    def iter_syn_packets(address):
        for tcp in iter_tcp_packets(address):
            for eth, ip in iter_eth_packets(address):
                ip.contains(tcp)
                packet = eth.get_packet()
                yield packet

    def get_host_ips():
        return socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2]

    def iter_eth_packets((target_ip, port)):
        eth, ip = generate_empty_ip_packet()
        for source_ip in get_host_ips():
            ip.set_ip_src(source_ip)
            ip.set_ip_dst(target_ip)
            for source_mac in get_macs(source_ip):
                eth.set_ether_shost(source_mac)
                for target_mac in get_macs(target_ip):
                    eth.set_ether_dhost(target_mac)
                    yield eth, ip

    def get_devices():
        return scanning.values()

    def iter_tcp_packets((_, target_port)):
        tcp = ImpactPacket.TCP()
        #### values to set:
        # source port, destination port, sequence number, window, flags
        source_port = random.randint(2048, 0xffff)
        tcp.set_th_sport(source_port)
        tcp.set_th_dport(target_port)
        tcp.set_th_seq(random.randint(1, 0x7fffffff))
        tcp.set_th_win(32768) # window -> discovered this as default
        tcp.set_SYN()
        yield tcp

    # waiting and scanner interaction

    keep_running = [1] # True
    def wait():
        if keep_running:
            keep_running.pop() # keep_running = False
        while scanning:
            time.sleep(0.01)
##        raw_input()

    def add_scan((socketargs, addr)):
        ip = addr[IP]
        port = addr[PORT]
        family = socketargs[SOCK_INIT_FAMILY]
        if ip_known(ip):
            send_syn(family, addr)
        else:
            add_target(family, addr)
            notify(family, addr)

    notified = {}
    def notify(family, addr):
        now = time.time()
        if family == socket.AF_INET:
            ip = addr[IP]
            if notified.get(ip, 0) < now - NOTIFY_TIMEOUT:
                notified[ip] = now
                send_who_is_ipv4(ip)
        elif family == socket.AF_INET6:
            pass
        else:
            raise ValueError('unknown protocol family type %i' % family)

    scanning_lock = thread.allocate_lock()
    scanning = {} # device_name : device

    def send_who_is_ipv4(target_ip):
        eth, arp = generate_empty_arp_request()
        arp.set_ar_tpa(ip_tuple(target_ip)) # target protocol address

        for ip, mac in get_local_macs():
            arp.set_ar_spa(ip_tuple(ip))    # source protocol address
            arp.set_ar_sha(mac)             # source hardware address
            eth.set_ether_shost(mac)        # source hardware address
            if DEBUG_ARP: print 'send_who_is_ipv4: %s%s -> %s' % (ip, mac, target_ip)
            send_packet(eth.get_packet())

    def send_packet(packet):
        t = -time.time()
        for device in get_devices():
            if DEBUG_PACKET:print device, repr(packet)
            device.sendpacket(packet)
        t -= time.time() - 0.002
        if t > 0:
            time.sleep(t)

    def scan(device_name, device):
        if DEBUG_IFACE: print 'dev up: %s' % device_name
        with scanning_lock:
            if device_name in scanning:
                return
            scanning[device_name] = device
        try:
            while device_name in scanning:
                time, data = next(device)
                find_connection_response(str(data))

        finally:
            with scanning_lock:
                scanning.pop(device_name, None )
            if DEBUG_IFACE: print 'dev down: %s' % device_name


    def start_scans():
        for device_name in pcap.findalldevs():
            start_scan(device_name)
        start_scan(pcap.lookupdev())

    def start_scan(device_name):
        device = pcap.pcap(device_name, *PCAP_ARGS, **PCAP_KW)
        thread.start_new(scan, (device_name, device))

    def notify_loop():
        targets_lock.acquire()
        while targets or phase:
            targets_lock.release()
            try:
                do_notify()
            except:
                traceback.print_exc()
            # iterate over scanner phases
            try:
                phases[0]()
            except:
                traceback.print_exc()
            targets_lock.acquire()
        targets_lock.release()

    def get_state():
        return len(targets)

    last_state = [time.time(), get_state()]

    def state_has_not_changed_for(timeout):
        now = time.time()
        state = get_state()
        if state != last_state[STATE_STATE]:
            last_state[STATE_TIME] = now
            last_state[STATE_STATE] = state
        if DEBUG_STATE: print 'state old:', last_state[STATE_TIME] + timeout < now
        return last_state[STATE_TIME] + timeout < now

    def reset_state():
        now = time.time()
        state = get_state()
        last_state[STATE_TIME] = now
        last_state[STATE_STATE] = state

    target_save = [] # needed between phase 3 and 4

    phases = []
    phase = phases.append
    @phase
    def do_scanner_phase():
        # wait for wait()
        if keep_running: return 
        if DEBUG_PHASE: print 'initiated phase 1 = waiting'
        reset_state()
        phases.pop(0)
        if not targets:
            give_up()
    @phase
    def do_scanner_phase():
        # wait to timeout without exiting wait
        # send ip packets to the host to enable 
        if not state_has_not_changed_for(timeout): return
        if DEBUG_PHASE: print 'initiated phase 2 = send packets'
        send_packets_to_addresses_to_sniff_mac()
        reset_state()
        phases.pop(0)
        if not targets:
            give_up()
    @phase
    def do_scanner_phase():
        # wait to timeout without exiting wait
        # set all ip hosts to have all mac addresses
        if not state_has_not_changed_for(timeout): return
        if DEBUG_PHASE: print 'initiated phase 3 = send to all'
        target_save.extend(targets[:])
        associate_all_ip_with_all_mac_addresses()
        reset_state()
        phases.pop(0)
        if not targets:
            give_up()
    @phase
    def do_scanner_phase():
        # wait to timeout without exiting wait
        # start broadcasting instead of using real mac address
        if not state_has_not_changed_for(timeout): return
        if DEBUG_PHASE: print 'initiated phase 4 = broadcast'
        if add_broadcast_to_all_mac_addresses():
            with targets_lock:
                targets.extend(target_save)
            reset_state()
        give_up()
    @phase
    def do_scanner_phase():
        # wait to timeout without exiting wait
        # give up
        if not state_has_not_changed_for(timeout): return
        if DEBUG_PHASE: print 'initiated phase 5 = give up'
        for device_name in scanning.keys():
            scanning.pop(device_name)
        reset_state()
        phases.insert(0, phases.pop(-1))
    @phase
    def do_scanner_phase():
        pass

    def give_up():
        phases.insert(0, phases.pop(-2))

    def send_packets_to_addresses_to_sniff_mac():
        udp_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        for host in target_hosts:
            send_udp(udp_sock, host)
        try:
            raw_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
        except:
            sys.stderr.write('higher previleges needed to perform raw socket packet send\n')
            return
        for target in targets:
            send_raw(raw_sock, target)

    def send_raw(raw_sock, (family, addr)):
        if family == socket.AF_INET:
            send_raw_ipv4(raw_sock, addr)
        elif family == socket.AF_INET6:
            pass # todo: ipv6
        else:
            raise ValueError('invalid family %s' % (family,))

    def send_raw_ipv4(raw_sock, addr):
        for tcp in iter_tcp_packets(addr):
            if DEBUG_PHASE2: print 'sending tcp raw', repr(tcp.get_packet()), addr
            try:
                raw_sock.sendto(tcp.get_packet(), addr)
            except ():
                pass


    def send_udp(s, host):
        # send an udp packet to sniff mac address

        try:
            s.sendto(':)', (host, random.randint(0, 0xffff)))
        except socket_error as e:
            if DEBUG_PHASE2: print 'failed: send to %r %s' % (host, e)
        else:
            if DEBUG_PHASE2: print 'succeded: send to %r' % (host,)
        s.close()


    def associate_all_ip_with_all_mac_addresses():
        macs = set()
        for mac in mac_addresses.values():
            macs.update(mac)
        for mac in mac_addresses.values():
            mac.update(macs)
        if DEBUG_PHASE: print 'macs:', [mac for mac in macs]

    def add_broadcast_to_all_mac_addresses():
        updated_mac = False
        BC = ('B', ETHER_BROADCAST)
        for mac in mac_addresses.values():
            updated_mac = updated_mac or not BC in mac
            mac.add(('B', ETHER_BROADCAST))
        return updated_mac


    def do_notify():
        t = time.time()
        notified = set()
        for target in targets[:]:
            ip = target[1][IP]
            if ip in notified:
                continue
            if DEBUG_SYN:
                print 'nofifying %s' % ip,
            if ip_known(ip):
                if DEBUG_SYN:print 'send_syn', target[PORT]
                send_syn(*target)
                targets.remove(target)
            else:
                if DEBUG_SYN:print 'notify'
                notify(*target)
                notified.add(ip)
        t -= time.time() - NOTIFY_TIMEOUT
        if t > 0:
            time.sleep(t)

    def start_notify_loop():
        thread.start_new(notify_loop, ())

    store_ip_mac_resolution_for(socket.gethostname())
    start_scans()
    start_notify_loop()

    return obj(wait = wait, add_scan = add_scan)


def main():
    host, ports, timeout = parseArgs(DEFAULT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT)
    scanner = start_scan(timeout)
    for connection in connections(host, ports):
        scanner.add_scan(connection)
    scanner.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code written in Python with working `pcapy`. This might be of help for many.

```
'''
Packet sniffer in python using the pcapy python library

Project website
http://oss.coresecurity.com/projects/pcapy.html
'''

import socket
from struct import *
import datetime
import pcapy
import sys
import socket

def main(argv):
    #list all devices
    devices = pcapy.findalldevs()
    print devices

    errbuf = ""

    #ask user to enter device name to sniff
    print "Available devices are :"
    for d in devices :
        print d

    dev = raw_input("Enter device name to sniff : ")

    print "Sniffing device " + dev

    '''
    open device
    # Arguments here are:
    #   device
    #   snaplen (maximum number of bytes to capture _per_packet_)
    #   promiscious mode (1 for true)
    #   timeout (in milliseconds)
    '''
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
    s = socket.socket();
    #s.settimeout(100);    

    #dev = 'eth0' 
    cap = pcapy.open_live(dev , 65536 , 1 , 1000)

   #start sniffing packets
    while(1) :
        (header, packet) = cap.next()
        #print ('%s: captured %d bytes, truncated to %d bytes' %(datetime.datetime.now(), header.getlen(), header.getcaplen()))
        parse_packet(packet)

    #start sniffing packets
    #while(1) :

    #print ('%s: captured %d bytes, truncated to %d bytes' %(datetime.datetime.now(), header.getlen(), header.getcaplen()))


#Convert a string of 6 characters of ethernet address into a dash separated hex string
def eth_addr (a) :
    b = "%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x" % (ord(a[0]) , ord(a[1]) , ord(a[2]), ord(a[3]), ord(a[4]) , ord(a[5]))
    return b

#function to parse a packet
def parse_packet(packet) :

    #parse ethernet header
    eth_length = 14

    eth_header = packet[:eth_length]
    eth = unpack('!6s6sH' , eth_header)
    eth_protocol = socket.ntohs(eth[2])
    print 'Destination MAC : ' + eth_addr(packet[0:6]) + ' Source MAC : ' + eth_addr(packet[6:12]) + ' Protocol : ' + str(eth_protocol)

    #Parse IP packets, IP Protocol number = 8
    if eth_protocol == 8 :
        #Parse IP header
        #take first 20 characters for the ip header
        ip_header = packet[eth_length:20+eth_length]

        #now unpack them :)
        iph = unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_header)

        version_ihl = iph[0]
        version = version_ihl >> 4
        ihl = version_ihl & 0xF

        iph_length = ihl * 4

        ttl = iph[5]
        protocol = iph[6]
        s_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[8]);
        d_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[9]);

        print 'Version : ' + str(version) + ' IP Header Length : ' + str(ihl) + ' TTL : ' + str(ttl) + ' Protocol : ' + str(protocol) + ' Source Address : ' + str(s_addr) + ' Destination Address : ' + str(d_addr)

        #TCP protocol
        if protocol == 6 :
            t = iph_length + eth_length
            tcp_header = packet[t:t+20]

            #now unpack them :)
            tcph = unpack('!HHLLBBHHH' , tcp_header)

            source_port = tcph[0]
            dest_port = tcph[1]
            sequence = tcph[2]
            acknowledgement = tcph[3]
            doff_reserved = tcph[4]
            tcph_length = doff_reserved >> 4

            print 'Source Port : ' + str(source_port) + ' Dest Port : ' + str(dest_port) + ' Sequence Number : ' + str(sequence) + ' Acknowledgement : ' + str(acknowledgement) + ' TCP header length : ' + str(tcph_length)

            h_size = eth_length + iph_length + tcph_length * 4
            data_size = len(packet) - h_size

            #get data from the packet
            data = packet[h_size:]

            #print 'Data : ' + data

        #ICMP Packets
        elif protocol == 1 :
            u = iph_length + eth_length
            icmph_length = 4
            icmp_header = packet[u:u+4]

            #now unpack them :)
            icmph = unpack('!BBH' , icmp_header)

            icmp_type = icmph[0]
            code = icmph[1]
            checksum = icmph[2]

            print 'Type : ' + str(icmp_type) + ' Code : ' + str(code) + ' Checksum : ' + str(checksum)

            h_size = eth_length + iph_length + icmph_length
            data_size = len(packet) - h_size

            #get data from the packet
            data = packet[h_size:]

            #print 'Data : ' + data

        #UDP packets
        elif protocol == 17 :
            u = iph_length + eth_length
            udph_length = 8
            udp_header = packet[u:u+8]

            #now unpack them :)
            udph = unpack('!HHHH' , udp_header)

            source_port = udph[0]
            dest_port = udph[1]
            length = udph[2]
            checksum = udph[3]

            print 'Source Port : ' + str(source_port) + ' Dest Port : ' + str(dest_port) + ' Length : ' + str(length) + ' Checksum : ' + str(checksum)

            h_size = eth_length + iph_length + udph_length
            data_size = len(packet) - h_size

            #get data from the packet
            data = packet[h_size:]

            #print 'Data : ' + data

        #some other IP packet like IGMP
        else :
            print 'Protocol other than TCP/UDP/ICMP'

        print

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv)
```